# Removing zero values in geom_split_violin (introdataviz)

Tags: r, ggpubr

I'm trying to plot two box-plots of paired observations with using ggpaired and introdataviz::geom_split_violin.
Here

The problem is I have a lot of zeros. I'm fine with the box plots and the statistical test to take the zeros into account, while I would like to **have the violin plots without the zeros**.
I tried to replace the zeros with *NAs* but then I can't figure out how to have `ggpaired` and `stat_compare_means` consider their zeros.

Any hint?
here a dummy code for reference.

```
library(introdataviz)
library(ggpubr)
set.seed(42)

first <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,15,2)))
second <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,10,1)))
df <- data.frame(first, second)



ggpaired(df,cond1 = "first", cond2 = "second",line.color = "gray")+
   stat_compare_means(paired = TRUE)+
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin( trim = TRUE,alpha = .4) + ylim(0,22)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

You could use `ggplot_build` to get the layers of your plot where the fifth layer is from your violin. Than you can change the y values of the violin to NA like this:

```r
library(introdataviz)
library(ggpubr)
set.seed(42)

first <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,15,2)))
second <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,10,1)))
df <- data.frame(first, second)

# Plot
p<- ggpaired(df,cond1 = "first", cond2 = "second",line.color = "gray")+
  stat_compare_means(paired = TRUE)+
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin( trim = TRUE,alpha = .4) + ylim(0,22)

q <- ggplot_build(p)

# Violin layer remove zeros
q$data[[5]] <- q$data[[5]][q$data[[5]]$y != 0, ]

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)

plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

You could replace the zeros with NA's using the following code:

```r
library(introdataviz)
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
set.seed(42)

first <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,15,2)))
second <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,10,1)))
df <- data.frame(first, second)

df[df <= 0] <- NA
ggpaired(df,cond1 = "first", cond2 = "second",line.color = "gray")+
  stat_compare_means(paired = TRUE)+
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin( trim = TRUE,alpha = .4) + ylim(0,22)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, actually as I stated I'm fine with the box plots and the test to have the zeros. My issue is to only ignore the zeros in the violin plots..

Comment: @Michl, Edited accordingly! You can change the values in the violin layer using `ggplot_build`.